# ADS Error 1796: Connection problem in Beckhoff controller using twinCAT

Tags: ads, twincat

When I try to connect the Beckhoff controller using TwinCAT software, It shows an ADS error 1796 (0x704): 'ADS ERROR: Reading/writing not permitted'. I have tried disabling firewall and uncheking the ADS secure option. Still it's not solved.

Comment: [Here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/496162/twincat-input-port-error) someone got the same error code when a license was not activated. Are your licenses activated?

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you set the ads routes (properly). You need 2 ads routes. One on the client machine (where you run the development stuff or your tcadsdll based client) and one on the server machine (where the runtime runs).
The ads route on the client machine is used to translate the server ams net id in to an ip address/host name, i.e. to find the server machine.
The ads route on the server machine is used to check if client connections are allowed.
To create a route for the server machine you must provide credentials of the user under which the runtime runs on the server.
You can create both routes on the client machine. Click the TwinCAT tray icon and select Router->Edit Routes. This gives you a dialog. Click Add in this dialog, provide the information and click Add Route.